# Mapping a smbnetfs network drive using fstab and .smbnetfs.conf

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab

I want a network mapping to be available to the user via `smbnetfs` at system startup without having to type `smbnetfs /media/network` every time, so I used this entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
smbnetfs /media/network fuse rw,users,noauto,allow_other 0 0
```

And it works, the mapping is there and it mounts when I click on it using any file manager, but the problem is that it will look for the configuration file at `/root/.smb/smbnetfs.conf`, and the user won't be able to access the Samba shares with its own credentials.

How can I tell `smbnetfs` to get the right location for the user configuration file? I didn't want to change the `/root/.smb/smbnetfs.conf` file because there's different users in need to map this share.

Answer (score 2):

In the Files section of the smbnetfs man page, it says:

> Please  create configuration directory ~/.smb.  This directory should contain at least two files: smb.conf and smbnetfs.conf. You may copy smb.conf from the /etc/samba directory. You can find a sample of smbnetfs.conf in the /etc directory.

If this works as advertised, you should be able to bypass the root conf file there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the documentation on smbnetfs states that it reads ${HOME}/.smb for the user who issued the mount command and since **vmassuchetto** making mount through fstab, that user will be root.

There is however a solution:
In `/root/.smb/smbnetfs.conf` is a string:

```
#read auth data from ~/.smb/smbnetfs.auth
include                    "smbnetfs.auth"
```

If memory serves me well, by default this should be commented out.
If path to `smbnetfs.auth` isn't provided, as is in above example, smbnet fs will look for it in `~/.smb/`.
So you can place `smbnetfs.auth` anywhere on file system and with any permissions to provide the user the way to edit it.
I'd suggest **vmassuchetto** to uncomment this and create a file `/root/.smb/smbnetfs.auth` with flowing content:

```
auth USER_NAME "USER_PASSWORD"
auth WORKGROUP USER_NAME "USER_PASSWORD"
auth COMPUTER_NAME USER_NAME "USER_PASSWORD"
auth COMPUTER_NAME/SHARE_NAME USER_NAME "USER_PASSWORD"
```

First line will instruct smbnetfs how to handle all not specifically mentioned computers.
Second line will instruct smbnetfs how to handle all computers from workgroup and/or domain with that name.
Third line will provide credentials for specific computer and forth is for a share on a specific computer.
All strings should start with word `auth` for credentials or with `#` for comments.
All parameters can be encased in `"` to shield special symbols, same way as `"USER_PASSWORD"` in example above.
Parameter `USER_NAME` can be specified with leading domain name or workgroup: `DOMAIN_OR_WORKGROUP/USER_NAME`

And as last resort you can always use this command:

```
cd /media/network/DOMAIN_OR_WORKGROUP:USER_NAME:USER_PASSWORD@COMPUTER_NAME
```